# Tensorflow, train selected output units

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a single unit of a two unit net, this is the code, in which I compare it with a single unit net:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))

model1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['mse'])

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred[:,0])

model2.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['mse'])

X = np.linspace(0,2, 50)
model1.fit(X, 2*X, batch_size=32, epochs=1000, verbose=0);
model2.fit(X, 2*X, batch_size=32, epochs=1000, verbose=0);

x = np.linspace(-1,1, 50)
y1 = model1.predict(x)
y2 = model2.predict(x)[:,0]
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, 2*x)
ax.plot(x, y1, label='model 1')
ax.plot(x, y2, label='model 2')
f.legend()
```

I would expect to get similar results from the two nets, but this is the output:
[image]

The automatic differentiation should work fine with the slicing, so I don't understand what keeps the second model from being trained properly in it's first output.

EDIT: Since it seems people are misunderstanding the point of the question.
I know the whole thing above makes no sense. My final goal is to be able to train a net with a custom loss that uses the output of different output units in different ways, so here I was only trying the most simple version of that, with a two units net where one unit is used and the other ignored.

Comment: I don't understand either of you comments, would you elaborate what you mean? The two units model should output a matrix of shape [n,2] and the slicing out[:,0] should select the first column, which is the output of the first unit.
And why would should I add another layer? I know what I am doing make no sense, I'm just trying to train a single unit of a two unit output net to see if it works just to test the technique that I'm than going to use for actual purposes.

Comment: I really think it is you here that is not understanding what is going on....
I defined a new loss for the two units net. This loss only depends on the first output, so the gradient of the loss only depends on the weight of the first output, and this gradient should be exact the same gradient the first net finds, and the weight update should also be the same. The logic of the process is correct, there must be some technical problem I don't know about Tensorflow.

Comment: What I am doing in the code have clearly no practical purpose and make no sense, I'm aware of that, it is just a test. I have a two unit perceptron, and one of this unit is ignored in the loss, so its weight are not updated, and it is also ignored a test time, the final result should be equivalent to a single unit perceptron, but it is not, and you have not yet provided any satisfying explanation. To be satisfying you should point out a technical defect, or write out the mathematics that explain why it is wrong. But I really think you didn't understand the question and the code at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213246/discussion-between-claudio-p-and-pygirl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `loss` function to the following:

```py
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred[:, :1])
```

The shapes of `y_true` and `y_pred` in `loss` are `(None, 1)` and `(None, 2)`. If you do `y_pred[:, 0]` you will get a tensor with shape `(None,)`, and then both `y_true` and `y_pred` will be broadcasted to `(None, None)`, but the MSE computed will be all `y_true` values against all `y_pred[:, 0]` values, which is wrong. With `y_pred[:, :1]` (or, equivalently, `tf.expand_dims(y_pred[:, 0], axis=1)`) you get a tensor with shape `(None, 1)` and the MSE computation is correct.

Comment: Is there any reference about this stuff and how default tensorflow  layers menage shapes?

Comment: @ClaudioP You mean the `tf.layers` module? I haven't really used it, I think it shares code with Keras, but I don't know about this kind of details. It was removed in 2.x anyway.

Comment: No I meant keras layers, do I have to look directly at the source code to know what exactly happens at the shape and at the data before their shape is fed to the build method and than batch created and so on? Why there are this None shape, I could understand them in the case of single dimensional output, but why also when returning two dimensional outputs.

Comment: @ClaudioP I don't think there are detailed specifications for these things, the [Keras documentation on losses](https://keras.io/losses/) literally suggests you to look at the source. In general in a simple case like this both `y_true` and `y_pred` are 2D, first dimension being the batch size and second dimension being the number of "features" (size of label vectors for `y_true` and number of output units in the network for `y_pred`). Most times you don't need to care about it, but since you are doing something uncommon (different label and output size), you need to consider these things.